# Want to have the Post editor remembering the last editing position

Tags: themes, javascript, posts, editor, tinymce

As you probably know the WordPress *theme editor* remembers its last editing position, but I want my *post editor* to do the same (it jumps to the top if you save a post/page).... Any tips/hacks how to resolve this ? Help with this is very much appreciated !!

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the *Visual* or the *HTML* editor or both?

According to [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) it is possible to set the cursor position for a textarea element. That is good news, as AFAIK the Wordpress *HTML* editor is using a textarea element.

The Wordpress *Visual* editor in difference is based on [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). TinyMCE does not support a cursor position natively (I assume this only, and it's only backed this up by a first, quick googling ). So this is not possible out of the box.

But there are some resources that offer a method of how to do that with TinyMCE.

I think you could add a javascript that does the following:

1. On loading of the post editor, check if a cookie exists for the postId.
2. If so, set the cursor position. If not, do nothing.
3. Then set a flag that cursor capturing is enabled.
4. While cursor capturing is enabled, On each keypress set a cookie for the postId and the cursor position.

Done.

#### See also:

- [TinyMCE Forum / cursor position](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=8238)
- [What's the best way to set cursor/caret position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253303/whats-the-best-way-to-set-cursor-caret-position)