# Inserting code to HTML view from a pop up initiated from visual view

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am trying to insert html into the HTML view.What i have done is to have tinymce advanced(a wordpress plugin) button that throws a popup and in it is all the necessary things to insert the html.The tinymce buttons are however only visible on the visual view.

Question 1:

Is it a plugin or hack that can allow one to parse html inside the visual view

Question 2:

Is it possible to insert html code to the html view from a popup initiated from the visual view

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want in Q1, i.e. "parse html inside the visual view?"  As for Q2 inserting into either view inserts into both. Can you explain more what you are trying to do and your specific use-case?  There may even be easier ways to do what you want if we can understand what you need.

Comment: Why do you want the html in the "visual view" to be parsed? If you want your html parsed, add it to the "html view"...

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I am trying to insert html code on my posts and pages.I found an easier way by using a plugin called php on posts and pages;i can have the html inside php and that too should also work.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is still too unclear for me *(and apparently for others)* to be able to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Is it a plugin or hack that can allow one to parse html inside the visual view

Neither of both. The visual view is the visual view and not the HTML view. If you want to paste HTML, use the HTML view.

> Question 2: Is it possible to insert html code to the html view from a popup initiated from the visual view

Technically this should be possible, but it would mean that you need to create a plugin with javascript for that first. In case "hack" from your first question is about writing a plugin, then well, this could be done for visual view as well.

The [TinyMCE API](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:tinymce.api.3.x) is a good start for doing that stuff.

[This answer to the "Want to have the Post editor remembering the last editing position"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/want-to-have-the-post-editor-remembering-the-last-editing-position/3723#3723) question might be helpful as well.